# Disappear Control HTML when click submit in asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a subscribe block in my page, include text box and button submit. I have a view name SubMail, this is it's content :

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" 
 Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Areas.Admin.Models.SubscribeMail>" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server"><title>SubscribeMail</title></head>
 <body>

 <div style="color:#353535;font-size:small;font-family:Verdana;">

    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Subscribe For Latest Information:
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = 
                "flathtmlcontrol", name="Email"})%>                
                <input type="submit" value=" Submit " class="flathtmlcontrol" />
            </div>           

    <% } %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I used user control to render the content to my web page, This is my user control file :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<iframe src="<%: Url.Action("SubMail","Portfolio") %>" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" height="70px"></iframe>
```

The problem is : when I clicked button submit, after page done, The control text box and submit button disappeared in my page, Until I refresh a page, the control is appear normally in  my page.

Can anyone tell me , what problem is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control is in an iframe, when you post  the form the control contains it loads the iframe with the results of the action method the form posted to.

Comment: Thx , but could you please tell me, How can I avoid or solve that problem?

Comment: so how can I call all that control in my view to put in my user control? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clrear why this is in a control at all.  You could also look into partial views.

Comment: Can we use another control instead of iframe?